# MongoDb findAndModify issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I just came across an interesting issue with my findAndModify query, I have an application that receives around 2000-3000 requests per second and each request has a "token" parameter.

A sample request would be: http://localhost:3000/manifest?token=my-token&adType=TableView

When I get the request, I look for the token, if it exists I update the "timeUpdated" field, otherwise I insert it into my 'tokens' collection.

This is the query I use (I have a store library that "promisifies" mongo queries):

```
store.findAndModify(
          'token', 
          queryEntity,
          {
            _id: 1
          },
          {
            $setOnInsert: {
              token: tokenName,
              inventory: [],
              status: 'LIVE',
              time_created: now
            },
            $set:{
              'time_updated': now,
              'category': tokenCategory
            },
            $addToSet:{
              'ad_types': adType
            }
          }
        ).then(function (token) {
          // do something with token
        })
        .fail(function (err) { //handle errors });
```

Everything was working great. Yesterday however, we received an unanticipated spike in requests, and my findAndModify queries were appearing as slow operations in the mongo log and started bottlenecking other queries resulting in timeouts.
Is there something wrong with my query? Any way I can optimize it?

Comment: Couple of things. 1. Why a library to "promisify"? Since the native driver and many higher adaptations already support promises natively. 2. Why `.findAndModify()` in any form? Just asking because "update/create" does not **need** to return anything unless you really need it to, and mostly because you seem to want to emphasise ( common here ) on the high transaction load of your application, yet you are adding seemingly unecessary overhead with no explanation. So what's the real problem here? A: The lookup of existing data? B: The return of modified/orig document when you don't really need it?

Comment: Basically just looking for the context of what you are asking to be solved here, since it does not really seem that clear.

Comment: The library to promisify was implemented before my arrival, I am trying to migrate away from unnecessary and redundant libraries that are already implemented in the native driver. I am using findAndModify because it returns me the updated document, which I can then use to modify another collection in the following promise chain. I need the updated document to be returned.

Comment: I guess I'm not really that sure of what to ask either, in short form my question is this: my findAndModify query was working splendidly until yesterday when it suddenly started showing up in my slow ops log. No updates/deployments were done to the codebase.

Comment: Well, if I understand this correctly you normally operate at 3k read/write ops per second, plus another database operation in the chain which causes another 3k operations (read?) and now you got a spike of requests, so you're at say 5k req per sec, i.e. 10k db operations per second?! I guess you'll run into problems with a single machine at some point. Reducing the sync interval to disk might help at the expense of more data loss if the system goes down. Improving data/cache coherency could be a strategy, but that's hard to tell from afar. Have you considered sharding?

Comment: I'm seeing two emerging things here in the overall commentary. 1. Mentioning things like *"I need this ouput to add to another collection"* indicate a very relational model which you should either loose or change storage engines to something more suited. 2. A general indication of read/write overhead without much general clarity on what it is being used for, and for which if we cannot break down to true usage then there is no other advice than *"tuning platform/hardware"* which is really off-topic for a programming Q&A site.

Comment: To be fair, unless you can be a lot more specific, this is just *"It's not working anymore!"*. Though I have had similar frustration, I really don't posess the the crystal ball that tells me all of the coded routines you are using, the exact process and what really needs to be achived without being informed of this. If that cannot be broken down, then throwing more hardware/config at the server is really the only thing that answers/not-answers this.